# symfony2: Setting PdoSessionHandler correctly

Tags: mysql, session, symfony, symfony-2.1

I followed the symfony 2.1 cookbook page on using PDO for saving sessing data, on this link: http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/configuration/pdo_session_storage.html 
the thing is, on my dev machine, everything works fine....also when i clear the cache for dev or prod enviorment
but on my production machine (live server) i get the error:

```
 [PDOException]                                                                                   
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server 
through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

when tring to clear cache with `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod`

so there seems to be something different between my live server and my dev machine,although the code in config.yml is the same.

i am using these settings under `services:`

```
 pdo:
   class: PDO
   arguments:
        - "mysql:dbname=%database_name%"
        - %database_user%
        - %database_password%

 session.handler.pdo:
     class:     Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler
     arguments: [@pdo, %pdo.db_options%]
```

and when i do `ls -la /tmp/mysql.sock`
i get

```
ls: cannot access /tmp/mysql.sock: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Can you connect to MySQL with given credentials in the prod server out of symfony?

Comment: the mysql works fine, and the live site works fine....but it writes no session data inside the table, it seems like it is still writing on disk or wherever else.

Comment: This looks more like a server configuration issue than a problem of symfony. Are PHP and MySQL configured the same on both servers?

Comment: yes both are configured on same server. localhost= 127.0.0.1

Comment: @Dan Symfony2 overrides default php configuration. @Confidence - could you insert `phpinfo();die;` somewhere in your controller and check session storage in the `application` section (there will be also `default` section, which represents your `php.ini`, and `application` - your overriding configuration)?

Comment: @Dan if you mean 'session.save_path' 'Local Value /myabsolutepath/app/cache/prod/sessions' and global value is : no value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to your arguments in mysql:

```
services:
pdo:
    class: PDO
    arguments:
        - "mysql:dbname=%database_name%;host=%database_host%"
        - %database_user%
        - %database_password%
    calls:
        - [setAttribute, [3, 2]] # \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
session.handler.pdo:
    class:     Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler
    arguments: ["@pdo", "%pdo.db_options%"]
```

There's no database host on your configuration and the 1st parameter in the PDO class ($dsn) has two parameters seperated by a semicolon the dbname and dbhost, hope that will help, cheers!